# Adding filter in Janus Gridex

Tags: janus, gridex

I am using a Janus GridEX with multiple columns. I want to apply filter in gridex data based upon input value for a particular column in GridEX . I am trying to add an extra row at the top where i can input filter condition in a textbox for a particular column. I want to keep only the filter cells as editable while keeping rest of GridEX non editable. If it is non possible, then can I use FilterEditor to implement the same.?

Answer (score 3):

```
GridEXFilterCondition filter = new GridEXFilterCondition(GridName.RootTable.Columns["ColumnName"], ConditionOperator.Contains, TextBoxName.Text);
GridName.RootTable.FilterCondition = filter;
```

Comment: Please add some explanations to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic filtering is already available in `GridEx`. To enable it, just set these properties below:

In `GridEx` properties:

```
Dynamic Filtering = true
FilterMode = Automatic
FilterRowUpdateMode = WhenValueChanges
```

In `RootTable` properties:

```
Dynamic Filtering = true
```

In each column's properties, you can set the `FilterEditType`  and `FilterRowComparison` as you like.

Comment: How to keep retain filter after reload using filtergrid

Comment: Can you please tell how can we retain filters after refresh.

Answer (score 1):

You can Add Multi Condition With (Or-And)

this is an Example :

```
GridEXFilterCondition filter=
new GridEXFilterCondition(YourJanusGridName.RootTable.Columns["YourColumnName"], ConditionOperator.Contains, sgTextBox3.Text);

filter.AddCondition(**LogicalOperator.Or**, new GridEXFilterCondition(YourJanusGridName.RootTable.Columns["YourColumnName"], ConditionOperator.Contains, sgTextBox3.Text));

filter.AddCondition(LogicalOperator.Or,new GridEXFilterCondition(YourJanusGridName.RootTable.Columns["YourColumnName"], ConditionOperator.Contains, sgTextBox3.Text));


YourJanusGridName.RootTable.FilterCondition = filter;
```

Its help me to do My Work Item

Answer (score 0):

Click on the GridEx control and in the properties window set the following properties

```
FilterMode = Automatic

FilterRowButtonStyle = ConditionOperatorDropDown
```